# After replacing eregi with preg_match I'm getting: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ','

Tags: preg-match

I'm using PHP Timeclock and I've had to mod several pages due to outdated code.
However, I'm stuck on this one:

preg_match Unknown modifier ',' in timeclock/admin/timeedit.php on line 274

**preg_match ("/^([0-9]{1,2})-,/,.-,/,.$/i", $post_date, $date_regs))**

This page was unchanged from the source.  Any Ideas?

Comment: just a note that this page was updated due to **eregi** being not supported.  It's possible that 'eregi' simply got replaced with 'preg_match'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Perl delimiters from / to something else.

Answer (score 0):

got it with `preg_match ("^([0-9]{1,2})[-,/,.]([0-9]{1,2})[-,/,.](([0-9]{2})|([0-9]{4}))$^"`